# "Es limitado" vs "Está limitado"

Tags: gramática, adjetivos, cópulas, participio

Me como el coco un poco con el tema del uso de *ser* y *estar* con adjetivos, o, más bien, con participios usados como adjetivos.

Un ejemplo que me confunde en este momento es 'el tiempo es/está limitado', para decir que queda poco tiempo.

Bien, a mi entender, si estamos hablando del resultado de un process, por ejemplo el de *limitar*, tenemos que usar *estar*

> ya que hemos pasado demasiado tiempo en la librería, ahora nuestro tiempo está limitado

Pero a la vez, pensaba que cuando hablamos de una calidad inherente de una cosa, se tiene que usar *ser*

> ?? ahora nuestro tiempo es limitado

Pero, ¿es esa limitación una calidad *inherente* del tiempo en ese momento?  Además, ¿no estamos ante la pasiva en la frase directamente más arriba, es decir, *ser + participio*?

En fin, creo que tiene que ser *estar* lo correcto, pero no lo sé.  ¿Qué opináis?  Y correcto o incorrecto, ¿por qué?

¡Gracias de antemano!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En "ser limitado", no habiendo un complemento agente, "limitado" funciona como un adjetivo, siendo equivalente a "breve" o "reducido". Nunca diríamos que el tiempo está breve (a lo sumo, diríamos que el tiempo está siendo breve, en el sentido de que está resultando breve).

En "estar limitado", "limitado" es un participio y requiere un complemento agente, por ejemplo: *el tiempo está limitado por las circunstancias*.

Por los motivos arriba descriptos, me parece que en la oración en cuestión "ser" queda mejor que "estar":

- Ya que hemos pasado demasiado tiempo en la librería, ahora nuestro tiempo **es** limitado.

"Estar" quedaría mejor con un complemento agente:

- Ya que hemos pasado demasiado tiempo en la librería, ahora nuestro tiempo **está** limitado por el hecho de que va a oscurecer en breve.

Sin embargo, sin un agente "ser" funciona bien:

- Ya que hemos pasado demasiado tiempo en la librería, ahora nuestro tiempo **es** limitado porque va a oscurecer en breve.

Comment: Gracias, pero aún me queda un poco confuso.  ¿Dices que _sin_ un complemento agente un participio con _ser_ funciona como un adjetivo; pero con _estar_ el participio siempre es un participio y exige un complemento agente?  ¿Qué pasa en el caso de "el día está soleado", que, a mi entender, es la manera correcta para expresarlo. (Me han dicho que se usa _estar_ aquí porque la condición del día es el resultado de un proceso: a través de las acciones del sol hemos llegado a un día que ahora _está_ soleado).  Y, ¿Es lo que has dicho válido en general, o depende del verbo específico?

Comment: "soleado" no es un participio, sino un adjetivo.

Comment: Parece ser los dos: https://dle.rae.es/solear#YGkUDi3 (y https://dle.rae.es/soleado).  Suponía que era un participo usado como adjetivo, pero no sé los matices de esto...